rcparams not being applied to custom matplotlib class
I am trying to write a custom figure class around matplotlib.figure.Figure which among other things, automatically applies the correct formatting. Here's the current configuration:
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas

class CustomFigure(Figure):
    def __init__(self, figsize: tuple, layout: str):
        super().__init__(figsize=figsize, layout=layout)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        matplotlib.use("QtAgg")
        self.set_common_params()
        
        
    def generate_axes(self, num_axes: int, layout: tuple = None) -> Axes:
        if layout is None:
            layout = (1, num_axes)
        return self.subplots(*layout)
    
        
    def set_common_params(self):
        matplotlib.rcParams["figure.titlesize"] = 45
        matplotlib.rcParams["axes.titlesize"]   = 13
        matplotlib.rcParams["axes.labelsize"]   = 12
        matplotlib.rcParams["axes.linewidth"]   = 1.5
        matplotlib.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"]  = 11
        matplotlib.rcParams["ytick.labelsize"]  = 11
        
    
    @staticmethod
    def set_labels(ax: Axes, xlabel: str, ylabel: str, title: str = None):
        ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
        if title is not None:
            ax.set_title(title)
            
    
    def generate_pdf(self, filename: str):
        self.savefig(f"{filename}.pdf")
        
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    fig = CustomFigure((5,5), "tight")
    fig.set_labels(fig.generate_axes(1), "X", "Y", "Title")
    win.setCentralWidget(fig.canvas)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I've tried putting the rcParams in every possible location of the code, even before the class definition, but nothing works.
How do I get the rcParams applied properly?

What is the reason for setting the runtime configuration for all plots each time an instance is created instead of setting the default styling for instances of your Figure subclass?

I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow your question. Can you please rephrase in a simpler way? In either case, the likely answer is "because I have no idea what I'm doing"

If I understood your question correctly, your code does set the params as needed except for the figure title. That is because you are using a subplot which has 'suptitle'. So the parameter you set for figure.titlesize will not work! Check this instead:
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class CustomFigure(Figure):
    def __init__(self, figsize: tuple, layout: str):
        super().__init__(figsize=figsize, layout=layout)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        matplotlib.use("QtAgg")
        self.set_common_params()

    def generate_axes(self, num_axes: int, layout: tuple = None) -> Axes:
        if layout is None:
            layout = (1, num_axes)
        return self.subplots(*layout)

    def set_common_params(self):
        matplotlib.rcParams["figure.titlesize"] = 'large'  # this will not work since it is not for a subplot
        matplotlib.rcParams["axes.titlesize"] = 45
        matplotlib.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 45
        matplotlib.rcParams["axes.linewidth"] = 1.5
        matplotlib.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"] = 10
        matplotlib.rcParams["ytick.labelsize"] = 10
        matplotlib.rcParams["font.sans-serif"] = "Verdana"

    @staticmethod
    def set_labels(ax: Axes, xlabel: str, ylabel: str, title: str = None):
        ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
        if title is not None:
            ax.set_title(title)

    def generate_pdf(self, filename: str):
        self.savefig(filename)

    def clearfig(self):
        self.clf()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    fig = CustomFigure((5, 5), "tight")
    fig.set_labels(fig.generate_axes(1), "X", "Y", "Title")
    win.setCentralWidget(fig.canvas)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

